# Can't Interact With Any jQuery On Website?

Tags: jquery

I couldn't find anything on Google, so sorry if this is a duplicate, but my problem is I can't interact with any content. I'm using jQuery to create a very simple loan calculator, but you can't use anything. There's supposed to be sliders which won't appear. This is the URL: http://66.228.45.148:8081/

This is my jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
function update() {            
     $interest = 0.15 ;
     $perday = 15 ;
     $amount1 = $("#amount").val();
     $dayscount = $("#days").val();
     $amount2 = parseInt($amount1) + $interest * parseInt($amount1) + (parseInt($dayscount) * ($perday/100));
     $apr = (($amount2-$amount1 / $amount1 ) / ((parseInt($dayscount)/365) * 10000))  ;
     $("#amount2").val($amount2);
     $("#amount3").val(parseFloat($amount2-$amount1).toFixed(2));
     $("#amount4").val($apr);
}

debugger;

$("#slider1").slider({
    max:350,
    min:100,
    step:10,
    slide: function(event, ui) {  

        $("#amount").val(ui.value);
                update();

    }    
});



function addDaysToDate(days) {
  var mths = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
    "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep",
    "Oct", "Nov", "Dec");

  var d = new Date();
  d.setHours(d.getHours() + (24 * days));

  var currD = d.getDate();
  var currM = d.getMonth();
  var currY = d.getFullYear();

  return mths[currM] + " " + currD + ", " + currY;
}



$("#slider2").slider({
    max:30,
    min:1,

    slide: function(event, ui) {  

        $("#days").val(ui.value);
        $("#date").text(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days").val())));
                update();
    },
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $("#date").text(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days").val())));
    }    
});

$("#days").val($("#slider2").slider("value"));

$("#days").change(function(event) {
  var data = $("#days").val();
  if (data.length > 0)
  {
     if (parseInt(data) >= 0 && parseInt(data) <= 31)
    {
        $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", data);
     }
     else
     {
        if (parseInt(data) < 1)
       {
           $("#days").val("1");
           $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "1");
       }
       if (parseInt(data) > 31)
        {
            $("#days").val("31");
            $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "31");
        }
     }
  }
  else
  {
    $("#slider2").slider("option", "value", "1");
  }
  $("#date").text(addDaysToDate(parseInt($("#days").val())));
});

update();
});
```

This it the HTML:

```
Loan Amount<div id="slider1"></div>
Your Loan <input type="text" id="amount" value="100"/><br /><br />

Loan Length<div id="slider2"></div>


Days Loaned <input type="text" id="days" value="1"/><br /><br />
Repayment Date<br />
<div id="date"></div><br />
Your Loan
<input id="amount2" type="text" />
Interest
<input id="amount3" type="text" /><br />
APR
<input id="amount4" type="text" /><br />
```

I'm using handlebars and Node.js if that means anything. Thank you in advance! I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: could you please check if you have added the jquery library in your HTML, inside the script tag?

Comment: @PEJK he added jquery.

Comment: @Owen try to write your script in seperate file. Including jquery before the script js.

Comment: doing so made the bottom parts calculate but didn't fix the sliders. :(

Comment: @Sharmila It does allow me to interact with the bottom for a second but doesn't add the sliders in.

Comment: @Rush.2707 it's at the bottom

Comment: Should the "Java" tag on your question be "JavaScript"?

Comment: Did this code worked perfectly on localhost ??

Comment: @Rush.2707 indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the reason. My server was black listing https for some reason, though I don't remember doing it. I managed to fix it by replacing https:// with just // which fixed the problem. I just went in and unblacklisted https:// which allowed for me to use the URL. Thank you everyone, sorry for my brain fart.